# SqLite3 LoadError: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

OS: Ubuntu 16, Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.2
error:

```
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/work/cookbook/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/work/cookbook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.3/sqlite3_native
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@recipe_box/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/work/cookbook/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/work/cookbook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
```

when i change file sqlite3-1.3.11.gemspec
at `s.require_paths = ["lib"]`
 to `s.require_paths= ["lib/sqlite3_native"]`  i have the same problem with another gems (about 10) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails) 
[reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963018/error-incompatible-library-version-sqlite3-1-3-11-in-rails) gem not working 
what need to do to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963018/error-incompatible-library-version-sqlite3-1-3-11-in-rails

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula  reinstall gem dont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use [**lower**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833911/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-rails-tutorial?lq=1) [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636471/windows-ruby-rails-install-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native) of sqlite3 gem (**1.3.10**) instead v. 1.3.11
Before if needed [uninstall all gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx)
and write to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.10'
```

and use [`$ bundle install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

It's helps me